# Is there no manual include of Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I was starting some .php files in the /public directory of Laravel, which works, naturally, but it is separated from the standard Laravel system. In fact, Laravel wants you to you routes I know, and if I want to use some Laravel stuff I would think that calling

```
require_once 'path/to/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'path/to/app/Services/Myfile.php';
```

would let one use that... but for example "use GuzzleHttp", if used in myfile, gets fatal "Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist" in Container.php of Laravel.

I know there's [SHORTINIT](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/327137) in Wordpress though it is kind of a mess of requiring any file that you need and all the files with functions it uses... Is there something similar for Laravel? Or this is never properly used this way to hold php files within /public?

Comment: why do you want to use require? composer takes care of autoloading all the libraries.

Comment: Calling a php file in /public won't load anything else in Laravel will it?

Comment: I really don't think so. why would you put it there though? I suggest you make a folder in app, call it Helpers, and autoload the files in it in composerjson

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use require as composer takes care of loading the library files.
However when you add any new library or make any changes to routes or config files make sure you run the optimize command.

```
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: I'm not sure what that does or how that would let a PHP file including laravel php files work better.

Comment: Also, this was removed a few years back? https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-6-removes-artisan-optimize